# Originzational MVC and Angular keeping from injecting what I don't need

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

My problem is I have one ng-app. Does that mean I have to do dependency injection for plugins I may not be using on that given view? Example I bring in `ngTagsInput` does that mean I have to do it even when the view doesn't call for it? That would mean I have to include that js for every view even if it doesn't use `ngTagsInput`.

I have a very large MVC .NET application and I am trying to figure out what is he best way to handle bringing in external plugins.

I have some code like so in our Main _Layout template:

```
<html ng-app="ourApp">
    <head>
     <!-- all of our includes are here -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <directive></directive>
        <anotherdirective></anotherdirective>

        @RenderBody()    
    </body>
</html>
```

RenderBody is where MVC slides in our views from our mvc routing.That view may look like so:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/HomeAngular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <directive3></directive3>
</div>
```

App JS:

```
var app = angular.module('ourApp', ['ngTagsInput']);
```

IS there a way I can get around having to inject ngTagsInput on every view page even if i don't need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different ways to handle Dependency Injection (DI) in angular. In this first example, you simply define `ngTagsInput` before declaring the controller. If ngTagsInput is a service, for example, you'll need to return an object with methods that allow you to access the data inside of that service.

For example:

```
app.service('ngTagsInput', function($scope) {
  var data = {};

  return {
    getData = function() {
      return data;
    },
    setData = function(val) {
      data = val;
    }
  };
});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, ngTagsInput) {
  // ...
  $scope.tags = ngTagsInput; // whatever you want to do with it
});
```

> ***However, there's a problem...***

In the example above, if you run that code through a minifier, you'll get $scope turned into some variable (a, b, x, etc...) and angular wont know what to do with that.

---

In this method, we use an array. The last item in your array is your lambda function for the controller, which takes 1 argument for each previous item in the array:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngTagsInput', function(scp, ngTagIn) {
  // ...
}]);
```

This code can be run through a minifier just fine, since the dependencies are strings in the array and can be renamed to anything you want inside the function's parameters.

---

DI also works in directives, factories, filters, and services with the same syntax; not just controllers and modules.

```
app.directive('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngTagsInput', function(scp, ngTagIn) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Comment: I take it this works the same for a directive as well?

Comment: Yes, you can do dependency injection in directives, controllers, modules, factories, services and filters. I'll update my answer with another syntax as well.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you break down your application further into smaller modules instead of just one.  Then you can inject the smaller modules into the app module and only inject the ngTagsInput dependency on the modules that actually need it. That's how I typically break up my application by function or area.